# require с параметрами php

Tags: php, require

Здравствуйте, не могу понять, как сделать require с параметрами get

```
require("file.php?d=1");
```

Вот пример.

Можно ли так сделать? У меня не получается

Comment: Занимаетесь ерундой. Переменные из вызывающего файла и так видны в вызываемом, если они объявлены в глобальной области видимости. А если вам нужен $_GET, то и объявляйте элемент этого массива.

Comment: Так можно сделать только если обратиться по url `require("http://yoursite.ru/file.php?d=1");`, но это и правда ерунда.

Comment: Как-то иначе нельзя? Чтобы именно с параметром обратился к файлу, а в файле была проверка на параметр?

Comment: @Nekkich скорее всего у вас проблема в построенной архитектуре приложения

Answer (score 0):

В вызываемом `$url = mb_strtolower($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);` и дальше он с этим `$url` работает и обычно грузится просто в `iframe`.

Но иногда надо в другом скрипте в цикле вызвать тот файл, в котором `$url = mb_strtolower($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);` и он каждый раз должен получить разное `$url`.